# Is there an fmincon algorithm that always satisfies linear constraints?

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to perform a constrained linear optimization in Matlab with a fairly complicated objective function.  This objective function, as is, will yield errors for input values that don't meet the linear inequality constraints I've defined.  I know there are [a few algorithms](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/writing-constraints.html#br9p_ry) that enforce strict adherence to bounds at every iteration, but does anyone know of any algorithms (or other mechanisms) to enforce strict adherence to linear (inequality) constraints at each iteration?

I could make my objective function return zero at any such points, but I'm worried about introducing large discontinuities.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `fmincon` optimization algorithm to `'interior-point'`? `options = optimoptions('fmincon','Algorithm','interior-point');`. If I'm not mistaken, `'interior-point'` optimization should always search within the feasible domain.

Comment: Also have a read through the `AlwaysHonorConstraints` option's documentation.

Comment: Here's a bit of [self advertisement](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24298-optimize) that's relevant for this case :) It's a function I wrote, which uses `fminsearch` as the engine while allowing bound and linear/nonlinear (in)equality constraints. It doesn't care about discontinuities, doesn't need derivatives etc., and also has an option to strictly adhere to the constraints. But, as the engine is `fminsearch`, the algorithm scales badly and thus has poor performance for problems of large dimensionality...What do you call "complicated"?

Comment: Also, just as a general remark: returning zero is only useful if the rest of the objective function is guaranteed to be negative everywhere; I would return `+inf` :)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: Thanks for the code link.  I've set my objective function to return -Inf when evaluated at a point that doesn't satisfy my constraints, which allows the optimization to run but may have something to do with its present optimized result not actually being a local minimum.  The dimensionality is 20.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `AlwaysHonorConstraints` applies only to bound constraints and not linear equality or inequality constraints.  The `StartPointsToRun` option can be set to use only start points that meet both bound and inequality constraints, but it doesn't prevent those constraints from being violated at intermediate iteration steps.

Comment: @will can u write the specific form of your problem. You said it is constrained linear optimization with a complicated objective function. What does it mean?

Comment: Wait, did you say ***linear*** optimization? Why are you then using `fmincon` and not [`linprog`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/optim/ug/linprog.html)?

Comment: Indeed, as mentioned [here](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/optim/ug/choosing-a-solver.html): "`'interior-point'` handles large, sparse problems, as well as small dense problems. The algorithm satisfies bounds at all iterations, and can recover from `NaN` or `Inf` results.", which is true for both `linprog` and `fmincon`.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm not an optimization maven. A few ideas though:

1. Log barrier function to represent constraints

To expand on DanielTheRocketMan's suggestion, you can use a log barrier function to represent the constraint. If you have constraint g(x) <= 0 and objective to minimize is f(x) then you can define a new objective:

fprim(x) = f(x) - (1/t) * log(-g(x))

where t is a parameter defining how sharp to make the constraint. As g(x) approaches 0 from below, -log(-g(x)) goes to infinity, penalizing the objective function for getting close to violating the constraint. A higher value of t lets g(x) get closer to 0.

2. You answered your own question? Use fmincon with one of the algorithms that satisfy strict feasibility of the constraints?

If your constraints are linear, that should be easy to pass to fmincon. Use one of the algorithms that satisfy strict feasibility.

3. Sounds like this wouldnt' work for you, but cvx is an awesome package for some convex problems but horrible/unworkable for others. If your problem is (i) convex and (ii) objective function and constraints aren't too complicated, then [cvx](http://cvxr.com/cvx/) is a really cool package. There's a bit of a learning curve to using it though.

---

Obvious point, but if your problem isn't convex, you may have big problems with getting stuck at local optima rather than finding the global optima. Always something to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

If the Matlab is not working for you, you can implement by yourself the so-called [Interior point penalty method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_point_method) [you need to change your objective function]. See equations (1) and (2) [from wikipedia page]. Note that by using an internal barrier, when x is close to the constraint [c(x) is close to zero], the penalty diverges. This solution deals with the inequality constraints. You can also control the value of mu overtime. The best solution is to assume that mu decreases over time. This means that you  need to deal with a sequence of optimizations. If mu is different from zero, the solution is always affected. Furthermore, note that using this method your problem is not linear anymore.

In the case of equality constraints, the only simple (and general) way to deal with that is to use directly the constraint equation. For instance, X1+x2+x3=3. Rewrite it as x1=3-x2-x3 and use it to replace the value of x1 in all other equations. Since your system is linear, it should work.